# AutoSuggestBox - Change Query Icon Size

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to customize an autosuggestbox.  I've tried customizing the template:

[AutoSuggestBox styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185404.aspx)

With this I've been able to change almost everything I want, but I still can't figure how to change the font size of the query icon.

UPDATE: Today I noticed this issue no longer exists.  I have since installed the W10 Creators Update and several VS2017 updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the new icons of **Segoe MDL2 Assets** are sized and positioned the same. Details please reference the [Segoe MDL2 icons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font). And there is no font size relative property for [`SymbolIcon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbolicon).

But you have the following two workarounds for change the size of the query icon.

One is using the `CompositeTransform` for the `SymbolIcon`. Code as follows:

```
<AutoSuggestBox>
  <AutoSuggestBox.QueryIcon>
      <SymbolIcon Symbol="Find" Foreground="Green"  >
          <SymbolIcon.RenderTransform>
              <CompositeTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2"/>
          </SymbolIcon.RenderTransform>
        </SymbolIcon>
    </AutoSuggestBox.QueryIcon>
</AutoSuggestBox>
```

Another way to update the template as what you did currently.  The style of query button is defined in  `QueryButtonStyle` of the `AutoSuggestBox` styles and templates. You need to find it and update it. Instead of changing one property, you may need to add a [`ViewBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox) outside the `ButtonLayoutGrid` and set the height and width of the `ViewBox` to control the size of the icon. Code as follows:

```
 <Style x:Name="QueryButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                 <Viewbox Height="50" Width="50">
                 <Grid x:Name="ButtonLayoutGrid" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackground}">
                     <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups> 
                      ...      
                     </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                     <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                 </Grid></Viewbox>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set [`AutoSuggestBoxIconFontSize`](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/pull/4003).

```
<AutoSuggestBox QueryIcon="Find">
    <AutoSuggestBox.Resources>
        <x:Double x:Key="AutoSuggestBoxIconFontSize">24</x:Double>
    </AutoSuggestBox.Resources>
</AutoSuggestBox>
```